# Pyplot scatterplot legend not working with smaller sample sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm using the code below to generate a scatter plot in pyplot where I'd like to have each of the 9 classes plotted in a different color. There are multiple points within each class.

I cannot figure out why the legend does not work with smaller sample sizes.

```
def plot_scatter_test(x, y, c, title):
    data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'c': c})
    classes = len(np.unique(c))
    colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, classes))

    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    for s in range(0,classes):
        ss = data[data['c']==s]
        plt.scatter(x=ss['x'], y=ss['y'],c=colors[s], label=s)

    ax.legend(loc='lower left',scatterpoints=1, ncol=3, fontsize=8, bbox_to_anchor=(0, -.4), title='Legend')
    plt.show()
```

My data looks like this

[image: Data]

When I plot this by calling

```
plot_scatter_test(test['x'], test['y'],test['group'])
```

I get varying colors in the chart, but the legend is a single color

[image: Chart 1]

So to make sure my data was ok, I created a random dataframe using the same type of data. Now I get different colors, but something is still wrong as they aren't sequential.

```
test2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'y': np.random.uniform(0,1400,36),
    'x': np.random.uniform(-250,-220,36),
    'group': np.random.randint(0,9,36)
})
plot_scatter_test(test2['x'], test2['y'],test2['group'])
```

[image: colors2]

Finally, I create a larger plot of 360 data points, and everything looks the way I would expect it to. What am I doing wrong?

```
test3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'y': np.random.uniform(0,1400,360),
    'x': np.random.uniform(-250,-220,360),
    'group': np.random.randint(0,9,360)
})

plot_scatter_test(test3['x'], test3['y'],test3['group'])
```

[image: chart3]

Comment: The way you try to assign colors does not make sense to me. Can you be very precise about what the color should represent?

Comment: The color is just an arbitrary visual differentiation of each group. I happened to find a fix as I kept looking over it and posted it as an answer.

Comment: It's not a fix, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure not to confuse the class itself with the number you use for indexing.

To better observe what I mean, use the following dataset with your function:

```
np.random.seed(22)
X,Y= np.meshgrid(np.arange(3,7), np.arange(4,8))
test2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'y': Y.flatten(),
    'x': X.flatten(),
    'group': np.random.randint(0,9,len(X.flatten()))
})
plot_scatter_test(test2['x'], test2['y'],test2['group'])
```

which results in the following plot, where points are missing.

[image]

So, make a clear distinction between the index and the class, e.g. as follows

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(22)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def plot_scatter_test(x, y, c, title="title"):
    data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'c': c})
    classes = np.unique(c)
    print classes
    colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(classes)))
    print colors
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    for i, clas in enumerate(classes):
        ss = data[data['c']==clas]
        plt.scatter(ss["x"],ss["y"],c=[colors[i]]*len(ss), label=clas)

    ax.legend(loc='lower left',scatterpoints=1, ncol=3, fontsize=8,  title='Legend')
    plt.show()

X,Y= np.meshgrid(np.arange(3,7), np.arange(4,8))
test2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'y': Y.flatten(),
    'x': X.flatten(),
    'group': np.random.randint(0,9,len(X.flatten()))
})
plot_scatter_test(test2['x'], test2['y'],test2['group'])
```

[image]

Apart from that it is indeed necessary not to supply the color 4-tuple directly to `c` as this would be interpreted as four single colors.

Answer (score -1):

I feel silly now after staring at this for a while. The error was in the color being passed. I was passing a single color to the .scatter function. However since there are multiple points, you need to pass an equal number of colors. Therefore

```
plt.scatter(x=ss['x'], y=ss['y'],c=colors[s], label=s)
```

Can be something like

```
plt.scatter(x=ss['x'], y=ss['y'],c=[colors[s]]*len(ss), label=s)
```

Comment: Careful, this still doesn't make sense since you're mixing classes with indices of the unique classes.

Comment: I see what you're saying. In my data I'm always having a continuous series of groups from 0 to N so I just iterated the indices. It fails in your example because not all groups may exist. Your answer is the more complete solution. Thanks.